# dividing a file into multiple files using shell commands

Tags: shell

I want to divide my file into several files.

Below is the file that I have.

```
sort a # 3|4
sort a # 2|5
sort b # 1|2
sort b # 2|5
```

I want to have the file separated into below

#### file1

```
sort a # 3|4
sort a # 2|5
```

#### file2

```
sort b # 1|2
sort b # 2|5
```

As you can see, I divided them based on the second column. Since I have many different values for column two, It takes a lot of time to divide the file in the laborious way. How to achieve this issue?

Comment: You can *probably* use [`csplit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html) for this.  I haven't played with `csplit` much, but your use case sounds just right for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`AWK`** solution:

```
awk '!a[$2]++{ fn="file"++c }{ print > fn }' inputfile
```

- `!a[$2]++` - check for encountering unique second field value `$2` utilizing it as an index of the array `a`. Condition `!a[$2]++` will be evaluated to `true` only on 1st occurrence of unique `$2` value
- `fn="file"++c` - generating *filename* with incrementing suffix `++c`

---

Viewing results:

```
$ head file[12]
==> file1 <==
sort a # 3|4
sort a # 2|5

==> file2 <==
sort b # 1|2
sort b # 2|5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
split -l 2 test
```

This will generate 2 split files. Output of split files:

```
$ cat xaa
sort a # 3|4
sort a # 2|5
$ cat xab
sort b # 1|2
sort b # 2|5
```

Comment: This doesn’t split on the second column in the general case.